# SQL Server 2008 x64 Express Batch Insert Throughput Performance to CLR 'Instead Of Insert' Trigger

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, jdbc, clr

I have a simple NO-OP CLR Trigger being fired on a six field table with schema:

```
 datetime (PK)
 char (PK)
 int (PK, FK)
 varchar(1)
 tinyint
 real
```

which should be a total of 19 bytes / row inserted.

The FK in the above points to a table with schema:

```
 int (PK)
 nchar(10)
 ncahr(10)
 nchar(10)
 nchar(10)
```

I am performing batch inserts using a prepared statement every 1000 rows. I am getting for 150K rows inserted an execution time of about 11s. This corresponds to a throughput of ~.24MB/s (150,000*19B / 11s). Why so slow? I am not even talking to the disk?

I know that my client side code doing the sending is much faster. If I comment out the:

```
 executeBatch()
```

method in the client I get upwards of 5MB/s. What else is going on with the JDBC/ODBC connection and processing in SQL Server to make things so slow?

Is this really the throughput one can expect from SQL Server and an JDBC/ODBC connection in this case?

---EDIT---

The actual CLR code is very simple, literally an empty method:

```
 public class Triggers
 {
     [SqlTrigger(Name = "InsertHook", Target = ConfigConstants.TABLE_NAME, Event =   "INSTEAD OF INSERT")]
     public static void InsertHook()
     {
       //empty
     }
 }
```

> No-op in T-SQL Stored Procedure Total Measured Time was:3475297036ns
>   or 3.475297036sec INSERT COUNT:150000
>   0.783276657MB/s
>   43165.47 Rows/s
>
> INSERTING NORMAL into SQL Server Total Measured Time was:4884190118ns
>   or 4.884190118sec INSERT COUNT:150000 MB Sent:2.7179718017578125
>   0.556MB/s
>   30712.53 Rows/s

Sadly, I do not have control over the schemas I am working with here. I guess I am still shocked that even with one FK constraint that this is the best SQL Server can do?

In summary, if I had to rank the performance. It would be:

> 1) T-SQL NO-OP Instead of Trigger (Fastest) - 0.78MB/s
>
> 2) Inserting Normal - 0.56MB/s
>
> 3) CLR NO-OP Stored Procedure Instead of Trigger - .24MB/s

Comment: I haven't got any evidence, but my instinct says this isn't that unusual.  I would expect the limitation to be on the SQL Server side involving a trigger, because SQL Server has to execute the trigger individually for each inserted row.  Since it has to pass the data to the CLR for each and every record, this introduces a lot of overhead.  Essentially, even if you're using `executeBatch()` I'm betting the server has to use a non-batch method with the CLR trigger.  Try disabling the trigger and using your code to batch insert 150K records. Then try a T-SQL no-op trigger.

Comment: There's not enough information here to say and there are many possibilities.  It could be your SQL Inserts, or your table definition, or Index/Key Overhead, or the way your Trigger is defined, or the way your CLR is written, none of which you have shown us.  If you are concerned about your Trigger's performance, then measure how fast it is when it goes straight to the table.  That aside, I can tell you that 10,000 rows/second is considered about normal for non-bulk insert methods (depending on all of those other things I mentioned).

Comment: Need to do a benchmark with a T-SQL no-op trigger still. Added result for normal inserts.

Comment: Posted the numbers/stats you both suggested. I am disappointed there is that kind of overhead between T-SQL and CLR. Thanks for the dialog.